# Notify Icon memory leak?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a small c# winform app that only  has one form and it only has a notifyIcon object. The form never gets shown in fact. I coded the notify icon to update the .Text property when the mouse is moved over the icon. I've noticed that the memory steadily increases, in increments of 8 bytes, when I move the mouse over it.

I'm sure it's the fact that I'm setting the .Text property over and over. Since a string is immutable, and a new one is created with each setter, I can understand this but I thought eventually the garbage collector would clean things up.

What should I do to keep the memory from increasing? I've eliminated the possibility of the TimeSpan object being the culprit because I've tried using it as a class-level object and never instantiating it more than once. This provided no different results so I just declare and instantiate a new one each time for now.

```
private const string TEMPLATE = "Time remaining: {0}h {1}m {2}s";
        private void notifyIcon1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan((_targetTime - DateTime.Now).Ticks);
            notifyIcon1.Text = string.Format(TEMPLATE, ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
            //I think it's this .Text property that's increasing the memory usage.
        }
```

Comment: Why do you need to keep the memory from increasing?  Are you getting an out of memory exception?

Comment: How are you watching the memory usage? If you're watching Task Manager, know that it's not reliable. Are you *certain* that the memory increases without bound? Have you run out of memory this way? If you keep going, does memory usage level off after a while? The garbage collector will let memory usage increase quite a bit before cleaning up. There's no particular reason for it to clean up as long as there isn't any undue memory pressure. Most importantly, it's *highly unlikely* that the code you show is an actual memory leak.

Comment: Only for testing: call `GC.Collect` after assigning new string to `notifyIcon1.Text`. Then check if memory still continue encreasing

Comment: I agree that there is probably no memory leak...just a wasteful .Net run-time.  By the way, you don't need to create a new TimeSpan from the ticks, just use the result of the subtraction directly: `TimeSpan ts = _targetTime - DateTime.Now;`

Comment: @Idle_Mind: Wasteful .NET run-time? Depends on your point of view. One could argue that it's wasteful to run the GC if there's no memory pressure.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, everyone. Idle_Mind, that's a good suggestion. I'll probably change my code to that.

Comment: The memory usage was monitored using Task Manager, yes. I noticed it was up to 60 megs shortly before writing up this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, it's obviously the `string.Format(..)` function which allocates the memory.
As you can see here, the method returns a 'copy' of your string: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx#Format_Returns
Note that as suggested in the comments, your code is definitely not creating a memory leak, the garbage collector is just a lazy implementation and it probably has no reason to collect the unused memory as there is so few of it.